# Why do I get none instead of getting the data? How do I fix this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8, whois, pywhois

I use python whois #https://pypi.org/project/python-whois/
In most cases, I get None. Help please
How to solve this problem?

```
import whois


w = whois.whois('job.kg')
print(w.domain_name, w.creation_date, w.expiration_date)
print(w)
```

```
JOB.KG Fri Oct 29 23:17:57 2004 None
   
{
  "domain_name": "JOB.KG",
  "registrar": "ISP AsiaInfo (+996 312 964488)",
  "registrant_name": null,
  "registrant_address": null,
  "registrant_phone_number": null,
  "registrant_email": null,
  "name_servers": "NS1.ZP.RU \nNS4",
  "creation_date": "Fri Oct 29 23:17:57 2004",
  "expiration_date": null,
  "updated_date": ":  Mon Oct 12 18:46:24 2020"
}
```

Comment: The only None is for expiration data. I do not see other None's. I see `'null'` - which probably means that whois has no data for this key... as `'null'` is not python'ish

Comment: But when I check through the service [here](https://2ip.ru/whois/#result-anchor) Output such information that the expiration date is not empty.  ``Record created: Fri Oct 29 23:17:57 2004
Record last updated on: Mon Oct 12 18:46:24 2020
Record expires on: Wed Nov 3 23:59:00 2021``